# Nodemailer from domain name

Tags: node.js, email, mail-server, nodemailer

I working on a server that has at least two domain names associated with it.  In nodemailer, when I set the from field, I am unable to get one of the domain names to show up in the received email.

Here is an example that illustrates the problem.  Lets say I have a server with domain names domain.com and other-domain.com associated with it.

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

transporter.sendMail({
  from: 'some@domain.com',
  to: 'some@email.com',
  subject: 'Some subject',
  text: 'Some text'
});
```

The received email will have a from field of `some@other-domain.com`.  I tried using a made up domains for the from field, and the emails come through with the made up domains.  But when I try to use one of the specific domains associated with the server, the other domain associated with the server comes up in the received email.

Does anyone know why this is happening?  And, is there anyway to force nodemailer to use exactly what is writing in the from field?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you need to setup you business email account by [apps.google.com](https://apps.google.com/) follow alls steps there. And after, you should setup transporter, depend of your nodemailer version, like `var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport('smtps://NAME@YOUR_DOMAIN:YOUR_PASSWORT@smtp.gmail.com');` in this case for nodemailer 2.0.1 . 
Good luck!